# Powershell loop only execute command in the last loop why?

Tags: loops, powershell

I am writing a simple powershell script which read a list of user name from a text file, for each name run command "Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $name} | select name" however the code only done the search for the last name on the list, rather then everyone in the list, anyone can explain why that happened?

```
foreach($name in $(gc .\tmp\checkname.txt))
{
   Write-Host "checking $name now"
   Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $name} | select name

}
```

the output as below

```
checking Donna Anthes   now
checking Jessica Kelly  now
checking Malcolm Page   now
checking Rommie Redlich now

name          
----          
Rommie Redlich
```

I would expect the output like below

```
checking Donna Anthes   now
name          
----          
Donna Anthes


checking Jessica Kelly  now
name          
---- 
Jessica Kelly

checking Malcolm Page   now
name          
---- 
Malcolm Page

checking Rommie Redlich now

name          
----          
Rommie Redlich
```

Comment: That doesn't mean it only executed the command on the last loop, it means Get-ADUser only matched the name on the last loop.

Comment: You may want to take advantage of Ambiguous Name Resolution: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(anr=$name))"`

Comment: If that output is correct, all of the name names in your text file appear to have trailing whitespace, except the last one, which would explain why that's the only one it's finding.

Comment: Mjolinor's suggest is the answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let anyone who reading this question know Mjolinor's comment is the answer. with the white space at the end of each name get-aduser doenst return any result. I updated my code as below

```
    $a = $(($name).trim())
    Write-Host "checking $a now"

    Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -eq $a } | select name | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

got expected output

```
checking Donna Anthes now

Donna Anthes
Donna Anthes


checking Jessica Kelly now

Jessica Kelly


checking Malcolm Page now

Malcolm Page


checking Rommie Redlich now

Rommie Redlich
Rommie Redlich
```